# Soyuz thruster placement

Tags: spacecraft, soyuz-spacecraft, rcs

I notice that the Soyuz uses two high-thrust thrusters to translate in one direction along an axis, however some of the thrusters are located at a slight angle on either side of this axis, rather than both being exactly on it.

Why are they angled like this? Some of the translation thrusters below are angled through the center of mass (21/22 and 25/26), and some are parallel (19/20 and 23/24), and some are even angled inwards (13-16).

[image]

Comment: Even if you can't add the image in the post, you can still add a link to an external page.

Comment: Have you seen a photo that shows it?

Comment: No, but I have a schematic in a book which shows it. I do not have the rights to redistribute images from it.

Answer (score 2):

Its hard to picture but a typical explanation for the configuration you have described is because both thrusters go through the centre of mass AND that the thrusters are a redundant pair, rather than used together.

- The alternative that you described "*two thrusters located fore and
  aft of each other and exactly in line with the vertical axis*" means
  that when looked at through that vertical axis they would both create
  a torque about another axis perpendicular to that vertical.

If this misses the point please feel free to use it to strengthen the question.

Comment: I have added a diagram and rephrased the question a bit. I think the thrusters are always operated as a pair (the attitude thrusters (separate) have backups, but not these). I'm wondering if this arrangement allows for continued easy operation with failure of one thruster? It'd only result in the translation axis being slightly misaligned. In the Apollo LM I think they had to shut down the thruster opposite the failed one, to prevent large torques? The LM does have some diminished capabilities when thrusters fail, but the selection logic is rather complex and I don't understand the limitations

Comment: @Innovine I've just seen the diagram. The siting of thrusters 1-8 seemingly right at the back of the service module suggests these will provide a torque around the CoM rather than a translation - unless there is more to it than that. I'd be guessing to go further but someone here will have better knowledge. It would help to know as much about the set up as there is information for. Is there any clue as to the total suite of thrusters beyond the ones visible (1-8 and 13-16). Is there any discussion of mission phases?

Comment: ah, good catch, the 1-8 thrusters in the diagram are the attitude control ones, not the translation ones, but some of the translation ones are similarly angled. I will update the question with the full diagram, although it does not really shed much more light. The diagram is taken from the crew operations manual.

Answer (score 0):

This configuration is common because it means that, while, when used together, a small amount of the thrust from each thrust is wasted, individually, no thruster will impart a rotational moment upon the vehicle. This is because each thrust axis runs through the center of mass.

Why is this good? It's because it dramatically simplifies the control requirements if a single thruster fails. Dealing with rotation's a lot easier than slightly off-angle translation.

The same principle's used in many other places, especially with strap-on solid rocket boosters (see any of the Delta, Atlas, or Vulcan families for examples). I think (but am not sure) it's also partly the case with the Shuttle's own RCS (and of course the SSMEs).